# Java containsAll does not return true when given lists

Tags: java, contains, subset, hashset

I want to check an array is subset of another array.

The program prints false, but I expect true. Why isn't containsAll returning true?

```
int[] subset;
subset = new int[3];
subset[0]=10;
subset[1]=20;
subset[2]=30;

int[] superset;
superset = new int[5];
superset[0]=10;
superset[1]=20;
superset[2]=30;
superset[3]=40;
superset[4]=60;
HashSet sublist = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(subset));
HashSet suplist = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(superset));
boolean isSubset = sublist.containsAll(Arrays.asList(suplist));
System.out.println(isSubset);
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski, that's reason why SO exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a subtle bug in:

```
new HashSet(Arrays.asList(subset));
```

The above line does *not* create a set of integers as you might have expected. Instead, it creates a `HashSet<int[]>` with a single element, the `subset` array.

This has to do with the fact that generics don't support primitive types.

Your compiler would have told you about the mistake if you declared `sublist` and `suplist` as `HashSet<Integer>`.

On top of that, you got `suplist` and `sublist` the wrong way round in the `containsAll()` call.

The following works as expected:

```
    Integer[] subset = new Integer[]{10, 20, 30};
    Integer[] superset = new Integer[]{10, 20, 30, 40, 60};
    HashSet<Integer> sublist = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(subset));
    HashSet<Integer> suplist = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(superset));
    boolean isSubset = suplist.containsAll(sublist);
    System.out.println(isSubset);
```

One key change is that this is using `Integer[]` in place of `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving *aside* your initialisation issues (as identified by NPE), you've mixed up your two sets and you actually want:

```
boolean isSubset = suplist.containsAll(Arrays.asList(sublist));
```

i.e. does `{10,20,30,40,60}` contain `{10,20,30}` ? (which, of course, it does)