# Primitive arrays in Java collections

Tags: java, collections

When I implement a Collection using generics that holds primitive arrays within Java what is actually stored within the array? Using generics to define collections means that I can only store an Object and if I were to do `ArrayList<Integer>` I can add an `int` but this is autoboxed into `Integer`.

If I were to define `ArrayList<int[]>` its perfectly legal as arrays are objects. I'm unsure though if what I actually end up with stored in the collection is `Integer[]` as the compiler performs some transformations and will use autoboxing to add to the array or if I can store `int[]` and the collection will store the primitive array as the array itself is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList<int[]>` will store arrays of primitives. There will be no autoboxing involved.

In Java, an array of any type -- primitive or not -- is an object and is therefore compatible with generics.

It is even possible to inadvertently end up with a container of `int[]`, as illustrated by this fun question from yesterday: [Java containsAll does not return true when given lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664396/java-containsall-does-not-return-true-when-given-lists)

Answer (score 0):

int[] never be boxed to Integer[].Arrays are always reference types, so no boxing is required.
Java always tackle Arrays as a object either it is a primitive array or Object array.
Here is a little detail about [arrays of primitives and objects](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-arrays.html).For further detail please see [Arrays of Primitive Values](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter03/arrays.html) and [objects](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/courses/110/lectures/ArrayOfObjs.htm).
I also suggest you to see this question [Java: Array of primitive data types does not autobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)