Java Collection with Arrays
I am confused how an collection is allowing to hold arrays of primitive data type, but not the primitive datatype itself.
What happens internally here?
My underlying question is how array is handled in Java as objects?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678972/primitive-arrays-in-java-collections

@Sören - Thanks but answer to it is more of a statement , I rather want to know why such decision was taken by Java and how it handles internally .

The present
In current versions of Java, there is a significant schism between reference types (objects) and value types (primitives). (See Wikipedia.)
Most of the language is structured around the idea of everything being an object, with the primitives often getting in the way and creating various issues and edge cases. Most notably, when generics were introduced, they only added support for objects due to primitives working in such a fundamentally different way that it would add too much complexity.
(If I recall correctly, primitives were originally only added as a compromise since mid-90s computers and the original JVM implementations would have made everything unusably slow if everything - including basic numbers - had always been objects. As such, they have always been "different" - more primitive, if you will - from all the other types in Java for performance reasons.)
As such, we can have a List<String>, since String is an object, but not List<int>. Instead, we have to wrap the int in an object: List<Integer>.
Now, modern collections are built upon generics, which don't support primitives. However, arrays are more fundamental and added long before generics. They do support primitives. Furthermore, arrays are objects, even if they contain int values, in the same way that Integer is an object despite containing an int value.
Now, since arrays are objects, this means that int[] is an object, meaning that it can be used with generics: List<int[]>. int is not an object, meaning that List<int> cannot be used.
The future
At least, this is the current state of Java. They have for many years been at work on Project Valhalla, which allows for the creation of custom value types beyond just int, double, and so on. As part of this project, they are trying to smooth over and bridge the gap between objects and primitives. In fact, it will reclassify primitives as just a specialized kind of object, a "value class", and the object-primitive distinction will be replaced with an identity-value distinction.
This project also includes "Universal Generics", i.e. finally tackling and solving all the issues with unifying generics and value types. As such, a few years from now, it may very well be fully possible to create a List<int> and this whole answer will be completely outdated.
For an update on Project Valhalla, fresh this week in 2024-10, see Valhalla - Where Are We? by Brian Goetz.

This helped me a bit , How do I check how are arrays and primitives implemented in jdk ?

You can't really do that. They aren't classes in the normal sense; they are fundamental parts of the Java language. Think of classes as "molecules" built using the "atoms" of Java. int and int[] aren't molecules, they are some of the atoms that can be used to build a class. They cannot (currently) be subdivided further.

The only way to see how they are implemented isn't to check a class (in the same way that you can look at how Integer or ArrayList are implemented), but rather to download the source code of the JVM itself. However, that wouldn't be written in Java, but most likely something like C++.

Basically, asking "How is int implemented?" is sort of equivalent to asking "How is return, new, or + implemented?" They are not implemented in Java, they are the building blocks that Java itself is built on top of.

Thanks , got it . Is source code of JVM freely available ?

There are several implementations, one of which is OpenJDK (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk). I'm not familiar with the codebase myself, but my guess is that the JVM itself is under src/hotspot

@anshu_anand See Java specifications.

I like the molecules atoms analogy.

Arrays are objects. Primitive types are not.
Therefore collections are able to contain the former, but not the latter.




int[]
int




Type system:
object
primitive


Can be added to a Collection:
✅
❌




Yes , arrays are objects . But it wont allow List<List<int>> but allows List<int[]>

Because List<int> is not allowed. Because int is primitive type and generic don't work with that.

@anshu_anand your comment is exactly explained by this answer. You can only use generics with non-primitive types. int is primitive, int[] is not.
